# How to make OLLVM work with Android NDK r21?

Tags: android-ndk

I downloaded and compiled ollvm from https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator
however tutorials about config ollvm works in android NDK are base on early version of NDK which does not work in android NDK r21
How to config

Comment: Did you manage to get it working with latest NDK?

Answer (score 1):

I found an [article](https://xz.aliyun.com/t/6643) which is using ndk-r20 .According to the article , **(any NDK version is available)**.So it must work for **r21** too .I didn't test it myself yet and also Its language is Chinese , you can translate it with google chrome .